# Routing Information Using trace.json file

Tags: unetstack

Can I get the routing information using the trace.json file?
Suppose I created a 3-node network.

```
node 'A', address: 1, location: [ 0.km, 0.km, 0.m], 
node 'B', address: 2, location: [ 0.km, 0.km, -900.m],
node 'C', address: 3, location: [ 0.km, 0.km, -1800.m],
```

added route from A to C via B `addroute 3, 2` and added route from C to A via B `addroute 1, 2`
from node-A, I am sending a msg `tell 3, 'hello'`
However, in trace.json the threadID or the messageID generated for the datagram at the source(Node-A) is not the same when that datagram is forwarded at the intermediate node (Node-B).
If I can get the routing information from the trace.json file I can trace the data packet from source to destination and calculate the end-to-end delay for the packets transmitted between source and sink.
Is information regarding the routing of the network logged in the trace.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is perhaps not routing information, but rather a way to associate datagrams on different nodes?

The `threadID` on each node is typically different, as the `threadID` is internal to the stack and is not passed across nodes. It is still possible to associate the `threadIDs` on different nodes by analyzing the `TX` messages in a simulation, and finding the `threadID` on the sending and receiving side of each. This is demonstrated in the [`traceviz` tool](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/tree/master/tools/viztrace). The code isn't difficult, if you want to look through to see how it's done.

P.S. If you wanted to keep track of routing information, you should find the relevant `EditRouteReq` messages in the trace.